# Filling in Empty dates using Calendar

Tags: java, date, datetime

i am trying to create a list of dates that is based of the user's start and end dates. This is the infomation that I have in my array:

```
Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 01, 01);
Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 05, 01);
//User defined start and end time simulation

List<Calendar> datesinDB = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,15));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,16));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,17));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,19));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,20));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,02,22));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,03,10));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,03,25));
datesinDB.add(new GregorianCalendar(2015,03,27));
//This is the data that I have in my simulated database
```

My code:

```
Calendar c = datesinDB.get(count-1);
    for(int i = 1; i < datesinDB.get(0).getActualMaximum(datesinDB.get(0).DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
        if(i == c.get(5) && count < datesinDB.size())
        {

            revised.add(new GregorianCalendar(c.YEAR, c.MONTH, c.get(5)));
            System.out.println(c.get(5));
            c = datesinDB.get(count++);
        }
        else
        {
            revised.add(new GregorianCalendar(c.YEAR, c.MONTH, i));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 SGT 1
Wed Feb 02 00:00:00 SGT 1
Thu Feb 03 00:00:00 SGT 1
Fri Feb 04 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sat Feb 05 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sun Feb 06 00:00:00 SGT 1
Mon Feb 07 00:00:00 SGT 1
Tue Feb 08 00:00:00 SGT 1
Wed Feb 09 00:00:00 SGT 1
Thu Feb 10 00:00:00 SGT 1
Fri Feb 11 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sat Feb 12 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sun Feb 13 00:00:00 SGT 1
Mon Feb 14 00:00:00 SGT 1
Tue Feb 15 00:00:00 SGT 1
Wed Feb 16 00:00:00 SGT 1
Thu Feb 17 00:00:00 SGT 1
Fri Feb 18 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sat Feb 19 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sun Feb 20 00:00:00 SGT 1
Mon Feb 21 00:00:00 SGT 1
Tue Feb 22 00:00:00 SGT 1
Wed Feb 23 00:00:00 SGT 1
Thu Feb 24 00:00:00 SGT 1
Fri Feb 25 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sat Feb 26 00:00:00 SGT 1
Sun Feb 27 00:00:00 SGT 1
Mon Feb 28 00:00:00 SGT 1
```

My issue is that my code only can do this for a single month and not any longer. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"do this for a single month and not any longer"_?  How to you attempt to go beyond 1 month? Do you get an error message? A stack trace? The computer emits a shower of sparks and melts down?

Comment: @JimGarrison It just stops after figuring out the starting month. Not as dramatic as you expect it to be.

Comment: Can you post your entire code, it's hard to get a grasp of what is happening from the snippet you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out after looking at joda-time after posting the question so here goes:

The solution is to count the day of the year using joda-time instead of my original way using date, month and year.

My actual aim is to pad in missing dates that are not in the simulated ArrayList that simulates data grabbed from a actual database somewhere. So it might look something like this:

```
Date     | Value
15/02/15 | 1
16/02/15 | 2
18/02/15 | 3
19/02/15 | 6
```

My aim was to create a arraylist that has all the dates of the month with values 0 if the date did not exist in my original db. The amount of months to fill in is identified by the start and end date so assuming in this case, i am asking to do for a month.

```
Date       | Value
01/02/2015 | 0
02/02/2015 | 0
03/02/2015 | 0
04/02/2015 | 0
05/02/2015 | 0
06/02/2015 | 0
07/02/2015 | 0
08/02/2015 | 0
09/02/2015 | 0
10/02/2015 | 0
11/02/2015 | 0
12/02/2015 | 0
13/02/2015 | 0
14/02/2015 | 0
15/02/2015 | 1
16/02/2015 | 2
17/02/2015 | 0
18/02/2015 | 3
19/02/2015 | 6
20/02/2015 | 0
21/02/2015 | 0
22/02/2015 | 0
23/02/2015 | 0
24/02/2015 | 0
25/02/2015 | 0
26/02/2015 | 0
27/02/2015 | 0
28/02/2015 | 0
```

So here are my revised codes:

```
DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");//formatter for display
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2015, 01, 01);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2015, 06, 01);
List<Dates> revised = new ArrayList<Dates>(); //populated array
List<Dates> datesinDB = new ArrayList<Dates>(); //
int count = 1; //index for arrays
datesinDB.add(new Dates(new LocalDate(2015,02,15), 1)); //data
datesinDB.add(new Dates(new LocalDate(2015,02,16), 2));
datesinDB.add(new Dates(new LocalDate(2015,02,17),22));
datesinDB.add(new Dates(new LocalDate(2015,02,19),14));

LocalDate c = datesinDB.get(count-1).getDate(); //initial data
int values = datesinDB.get(count-1).getValue(); //initial data

for(int i = start.getDayOfYear(); i <=end.getDayOfYear() ; i++){
    if(i == c.getDayOfYear())
    {
        if(count < datesinDB.size()){
            revised.add(new Dates(c, values));
            c = datesinDB.get(count).getDate();
            values = datesinDB.get(count++).getValue();
        }
        else if(count == datesinDB.size()){
            revised.add(new Dates(c, values));
            count++;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            if(i != 59){//some issues with 28/2/2015 due to leap year i guess
                revised.add(new Dates(new      LocalDate().withDayOfYear(i).withYear(2015), 0));
           }
        }
   }

    System.out.println("Date      | Values");
    for(int i = 0; i< revised.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(sdf.print(revised.get(i).getDate())+ " | "+ revised.get(i).getValue());
    }
```

All in all, this nets me what I need with some slight errors that I will fix. Thanks to those that answered.

Fyi, Dates is my LinkedList class that looks like this:

```
public class Dates {
    public LocalDate date;
    public int value;

    public Dates(LocalDate date, int value){
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate(){
        return this.date;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else if they are in the same waters as me. Holy hell 365 days is so hard to master.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad form to use constant numbers, look in the `Calendar` class for symbolic names for the constant you want to use.

Here's what I think you want:

```
final Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(2015, 1, 1);
final Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(2015, 5, 1);
final List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>(128);  // 128: fewer reallocations

for (Calendar date = start; !date.after(end); date.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)) {
  dates.add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Question and its code are confusing. The author does not state exactly what the problem is. And I cannot quite follow the logic of the code. Your output does not map to your code. Are you trying to get a count of how many rows in the database fall on each day of the date range? Are you trying to get a subset of database rows that occur within the date range? So I cannot give a perfect-fit answer, but I'll get you closer to a solution.

## Octal

Do not pad a numeric literal with a leading zero; that tells Java to interpret the literal as an [Octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base-8) rather than as a Decimal (base-10). So, `( 2015 , 02 , 15 )` should be `( 2015 , 2 , 15 )`.

## Avoid old date-time classes

You should not be using the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## java.time

The old classes are supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

The java.time classes include [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to truly represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Seems to be what you need. To fetch those from the database, use the [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class via JDBC. Minimize your use of java.sql; immediately convert from the java.sql type to java.time as you continue with your business logic and presentation to user. In your database define the column as [`DATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) type.

```
List < LocalDate > datesInQuestion = new ArrayList <> ( );
datesInQuestion.add ( LocalDate.of ( 2015, 2, 20 ) );
datesInQuestion.add ( LocalDate.of ( 2015, 2, 22 ) );
datesInQuestion.add ( LocalDate.of ( 2015, 3, 10 ) );
datesInQuestion.add ( LocalDate.of ( 2015, 12, 31 ) );
```

### `YearMonth`

For the boundaries (start - stop), if using only whole months then pass objects of the [`java.time.YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth startYearMonth = YearMonth.of ( 2016, Month.JANUARY );
YearMonth stopYearMonth = YearMonth.of ( 2016, Month.JUNE );
```

### Half-Open

In date-time work, a span of time is often represented using the *Half-Open* approach. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Following the Question’s example, we will run from months of January to June so as to include all of May.

```
LocalDate start = startYearMonth.atDay ( 1 );
LocalDate stop = stopYearMonth.atDay ( 1 );  // Half-open approach, running up to but not including this date.
```

Prepare a pair of lists to store the dates found to be within our range and to store the dates that have no matches found in our target list.

```
List < LocalDate > datesInRange = new ArrayList <> ( );
List < LocalDate > datesVoid = new ArrayList <> ( );
```

Loop each date within our range. Search our target list for any matches.

```
LocalDate localDate = start;
while ( localDate.isBefore ( stop ) ) { // Loop through our date range from 'start' to 'stop', with 'stop' being exclusive.
    if ( datesInQuestion.contains ( localDate ) ) {
        datesInRange.add ( localDate );
    } else {
        datesVoid.add ( localDate );
    }
```

Perhaps you want to know how many times this date appears in the collection 'datesInQuestion'. The [`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) utility class (notice the ending 's')

```
    int frequency = Collections.frequency ( datesInQuestion, localDate );
```

Set up next loop. Increment to the next date.

```
    localDate = localDate.plusDays ( 1 );
}
```

The looping is complete at this point.

Perhaps you want to know the target dates that fell outside our range. Duplicate the list of dates-in-question. Remove the ones found to be within our range. The remaining must be outside the range.

```
List < LocalDate > datesOutsideRange = new ArrayList <> ( datesInQuestion ); // Duplicate the collection of dates-in-question.
boolean anyRemoved = datesOutsideRange.removeAll ( datesInRange );  // Then remove the ones found to be within our range.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "datesInQuestion: " + datesInQuestion );
System.out.println ( "datesInRange: " + datesInRange );
System.out.println ( "datesOutsideRange: " + datesOutsideRange );
System.out.println ( "datesVoid: " + datesVoid );
```

> datesInQuestion: [2015-02-20, 2015-02-22, 2015-03-10, 2015-12-31]
>
> datesInRange: [2015-02-20, 2015-02-22, 2015-03-10]
>
> datesOutsideRange: [2015-12-31]

Note that our three dates of February 20 & 22 and March 10 do not appear in this longer list of `datesVoid`.

> datesVoid: [2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03, 2015-01-04, 2015-01-05, 2015-01-06, 2015-01-07, 2015-01-08, 2015-01-09, 2015-01-10, 2015-01-11, 2015-01-12, 2015-01-13, 2015-01-14, 2015-01-15, 2015-01-16, 2015-01-17, 2015-01-18, 2015-01-19, 2015-01-20, 2015-01-21, 2015-01-22, 2015-01-23, 2015-01-24, 2015-01-25, 2015-01-26, 2015-01-27, 2015-01-28, 2015-01-29, 2015-01-30, 2015-01-31, 2015-02-01, 2015-02-02, 2015-02-03, 2015-02-04, 2015-02-05, 2015-02-06, 2015-02-07, 2015-02-08, 2015-02-09, 2015-02-10, 2015-02-11, 2015-02-12, 2015-02-13, 2015-02-14, 2015-02-15, 2015-02-16, 2015-02-17, 2015-02-18, 2015-02-19, 2015-02-21, 2015-02-23, 2015-02-24, 2015-02-25, 2015-02-26, 2015-02-27, 2015-02-28, 2015-03-01, 2015-03-02, 2015-03-03, 2015-03-04, 2015-03-05, 2015-03-06, 2015-03-07, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-09, 2015-03-11, 2015-03-12, 2015-03-13, 2015-03-14, 2015-03-15, 2015-03-16, 2015-03-17, 2015-03-18, 2015-03-19, 2015-03-20, 2015-03-21, 2015-03-22, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24, 2015-03-25, 2015-03-26, 2015-03-27, 2015-03-28, 2015-03-29, 2015-03-30, 2015-03-31, 2015-04-01, 2015-04-02, 2015-04-03, 2015-04-04, 2015-04-05, 2015-04-06, 2015-04-07, 2015-04-08, 2015-04-09, 2015-04-10, 2015-04-11, 2015-04-12, 2015-04-13, 2015-04-14, 2015-04-15, 2015-04-16, 2015-04-17, 2015-04-18, 2015-04-19, 2015-04-20, 2015-04-21, 2015-04-22, 2015-04-23, 2015-04-24, 2015-04-25, 2015-04-26, 2015-04-27, 2015-04-28, 2015-04-29, 2015-04-30, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-02, 2015-05-03, 2015-05-04, 2015-05-05, 2015-05-06, 2015-05-07, 2015-05-08, 2015-05-09, 2015-05-10, 2015-05-11, 2015-05-12, 2015-05-13, 2015-05-14, 2015-05-15, 2015-05-16, 2015-05-17, 2015-05-18, 2015-05-19, 2015-05-20, 2015-05-21, 2015-05-22, 2015-05-23, 2015-05-24, 2015-05-25, 2015-05-26, 2015-05-27, 2015-05-28, 2015-05-29, 2015-05-30, 2015-05-31]